# about this .. operator in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

```
void _drawBackground(Canvas canvas, Rect shapeBounds, Rect avatarBounds) {
  //1
  final paint = Paint()..color = color;

  //2
  final backgroundPath = Path()
    ..moveTo(shapeBounds.left, shapeBounds.top) //3
    ..lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomLeft.dx, shapeBounds.bottomLeft.dy) //4
    ..arcTo(avatarBounds, -pi, pi, false) //5
    ..lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomRight.dx, shapeBounds.bottomRight.dy) //6
    ..lineTo(shapeBounds.topRight.dx, shapeBounds.topRight.dy) //7
    ..close(); //8

  //9
  canvas.drawPath(backgroundPath, paint);
}
```

what is this operator in flutter `..` and what are the uses of this operator.

Comment: `..` is different from `...`

Answer (score 2):

It is a dart notation that allows you to perform series of operations on a **dart object** without affecting the returned type of the object. It is called the [cascaded notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation).

This

```
List<String> titles = [];
titles.add(title1);
titles.add(title2);
titles.add(title3);
```

Can be written as

```
 List<String> titles = []
 ..add(title1)
 ..add(title2)
 ..add(title3);
```